# Issue conecting pentaho biserver Community Edition with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, pentaho

I need to connect Pentaho biserver Community Edition with sql server , I've followed all the steps of the installation, but when I try to add mi DB , Pentaho show me this error:

"This driver does not support Java runtime environment (JRE) version 1.7. Use the class library sqljdb"

I've copied sqljdbc4.jar into : biserver-ce\tomcat\lib

Can anybody help me, please? Thank you!

Comment: I've copied sqljdbc4.jar into pentaho\administration-console\jdbc  too

Answer (score 0):

I have got same error message.

I just remove sqljdbc.jar from lib path and keep only sqljdbc4.jar.
Then restart appserver.

Hope this help.